# Add a specific line after every Nth pattern match .. AWK SED anything you got

Tags: shell, search, sed, awk, grep

I have a file like this

```
Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now

Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now


Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now


Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now



Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now
```

I want to add a line wait after every 3rdh  match of "Find a hot chick"

So the above should read.

```
Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now

Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now


Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
**wait** 
Do the best part now


Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now



Go to Vegas
Play the blackjack
Earn a  lucky wad
Find a hot chick
Do the best part now
```

After every N the match of a string insert another line ( in this case its "wait" )
How best can it be done
I can add a new line after every pattern match 
but I want to add a specific line after every Nth pattern match 
Like this

```
sed '/"Find a hot chick"/ a\
    wait ' <filename>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk '1;/Find a hot chick/{if(i++==3){print "New line";i=0}}' yourfile
```

The "1" just does awk's default thing, which is to print, for every line.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what does the first `1;` stands for? (I'm pretty new to awk)

Comment: `1;` causes awk to print every line no matter match or not

Comment: A slightly more compact alternative, avoiding `if` and keeping conditions before the block *awk-style*: `awk '1; /Find a hot chick/ && !(++i%3) {print "**wait**"}' file`

Comment: @grebneke - I got something similar.  What I like about Mark's answer is that it's never calc'ing a remainder on a potentially large number.

Comment: @n0741337 - yeah. But, it's a typical song lyric, how long could the show go on? ;)

Comment: Thanx folks ...works !!! For all the  help you rendered - how I wish 1 para of the pattern could come true for each of you , daily !!!

Comment: Until [ -f babes_in_vegas ]

Answer (score 1):

With `awk` you could do:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
  counter = 0
}

{
  if ( $0 == "Find a hot chick" )
    counter++
  print
  if ( counter == 3 ){
    print "**wait**"
    counter = 0
  }
}
```

Put it in a file, e.g., `file.awk`, and then: `./file.awk your_file`

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed  '/Find a hot chick/{x;s/^/./;/.\{3\}/{s/.\{3\}//;x;s/.*/&\n**wait**/;b};x}' file
```

Explanation: (it is called "Dot count")

```
/Find a hot chick/ {           # find the key words
    x                          # Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces.
    s/^/./                     # add one dot in hold space. (such as ..$, ...$ etc)
    /.\{3\}/ {                 # check if there are 3 dots in hold space or not.
        s/.\{3\}//             # find the third pattern match, clean the dots in hold space.
        x                      # Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces.
        s/.*/&\n**wait**/      # add the contents OP asked.
        b                      # b label, Unconditionally branch to label. The label may be omitted, in which case the next cycle is started. 
    }
    x                          # Exchange the contents of the hold and pattern spaces.
}
```

If need be done by awk, here is the awk command more straightforward.

```
awk '/Find a hot chick/{k++;if (!(k%3)){$0=$0 RS "**wait**"}}1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

A small variation of grebnekes `awk` version

```
awk '/Find a hot chick/ && !(++i%3) {$0=$0"\n**wait**"}1' file
```

This will add a new line for every third hit of pattern to the line itself, then print all.